# Usemap not working in Firefox

Tags: html

I have following HTML text to show an image that contains a link:

```
<img src="header.gif" alt="" width="900" height="47" usemap="#logoMap"/>
   <map name="logoMap">
     <area shape="Home" coords="795, 16, 870, 30" href="abc.htm"/>
   </map>
```

Problem is that usemap is **not working in Firefox**. It is working fine in IE 7.0. My image dimemsion is 900 X 47.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your area tag you have "Home" which is not a valid shape.  Try "rect".  That should do the trick.

```
<img src="header.gif" alt="" width="900" height="47" usemap="#logoMap"/>
   <map name="logoMap">
     <area shape="rect" coords="795, 16, 870, 30" href="abc.htm"/>
</map>
```